# Jquery Get Class of Clicked DIV inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to figure out what button a user has clicked inside a DIV container, but I must be doing something wrong here. I keep getting a no attributes error. Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong? Here is my JS:

```
// Bind ButtonClicks
$('#jplayers .button').on("click",function(e){
    alert("Class :" + e.attr("class"));
    // Determin what button
    if(  e.attr("class").indexOf("play") > 0 ){
        // Play Clicked
        player.jPlayer("play");
    }else{
        // Pause Clicked
        player.jPlayer("pause");
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="jplayers">
        <!--First Player-->
        <div id="zen_1">
            <span class="player"></span>
            <span class="circle"></span>
            <span class="progress"></span>
            <span class="buffer"></span>
            <span class="drag"></span>
            <div class="button">
                <span class="icon play"></span>
                <span class="icon pause"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Second Player-->
        <div id="zen_2">
            <span class="player"></span>
            <span class="circle"></span>
            <span class="progress"></span>
            <span class="buffer"></span>
            <span class="drag"></span>
            <div class="button">
                <span class="icon play"></span>
                <span class="icon pause"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: e is the event, not the element clicked. use `this` to access the element

Comment: although if you are hellbent on using the event, I think you can access the element by using e.currentTarget. But using this makes much more sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in your case you can make use of the **`e`** parameter in the *callback* method in the `click` event.

[**e.target**](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) returns the respective element this being clicked by the user.

```
$('#jplayers').on("click", function (e) {
    // using this you can access the specific element 
    var className = $(e.target).prop('class');
    if (className.indexOf("play") !== -1 || className.indexOf('pause') !== -1) {
        alert(className);
        // you can access it using $(e.target)
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BurL6/2/) (with a simple sample code)

Comment: This still gives me the class "button"

Comment: I need to get icon play or icon stop

Comment: @user3167249 can you check with `e.target` this will ensure to get the class name with `play`

Comment: @user3167249 Update the code with a sample fiddle for understanding

Answer (score 7):

You can get the class by using `this`.

```
$(this).attr("class")
```

The `e` that you're using isn't the element but the click event.

---

```
$('#jplayers .button').on("click",function(e){
    alert("Class :" +  $(this).attr("class"));
});
```

Comment: This gives me the class "button" I need to get icon play or icon stop.

Comment: to find all the icon classes use `$(this).find(".icon")`